# Tizen watchface get last recorded values for steps & heart rate

Tags: tizen, watchface

How can I get cumulative data for heart rate & steps from Tizen watchface?
`tizen.humanactivitymonitor.getHumanActivityData('PEDOMETER')` & `tizen.humanactivitymonitor.getHumanActivityData('HRM')` will return data that is gathered only by watchface itself. But I want to get data that is gathered automatically and displayed in S Health and in other watchfaces.

C#, native or web approach are okay. I know, GalaxyWatchStudio have access to this data, but is too limited for me.

Answer (score 0):

SHealth is a service of Samsung, so I think you need SHealth SDK(https://developer.samsung.com/health)

Comment: So is it possible to use from within Tizen watch?

Comment: This sdk is only  for Android. so I think that you can make an Android app and send Shealth data to the Tizen app.